# How to resolve Runtime error 9, subscript out of range when getting last folder in a path

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Attempting to retrieve the last folder in a path using an array, it is working but returning Run-Time error 9, Subscript out of range at end of script execution.
[image: Screenshot of the line where error occuring]
`

```
Dim a As Variant
i = 5
For n = LBound(files) To UBound(files)
    a = Split(files(n), "\")
    FnameInLoop = a(UBound(a) - 1)
    Cells(i, 1).Value = FnameInLoop
    i = i + 1
    Next n`
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint (F8) on the `FnameInLoop =` line, run your code; when the breakpoint is hit, use the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) to output the value of `files` and inspect `a` and its `UBound`. "Subscript out of range" means you're accessing an array index that doesn't exist.

Comment: It has over one file, but should that occur, how would I both resolve the current error and provide checking to remove a future error of having only one file in files?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you, used locals window and a has the path split from "C", "user", "computer (C:\Users\work\Desktop) all the way to the end file.

Comment: But does that one throw the error you're getting? See, without a `files(n)` string that reliably reproduces the problem, it's very hard to help debugging. See [mcve] and feel free to [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you, used locals window and a has the path split from "C", "user", "computer (C:\Users\work\Desktop) all the way to the end file.  Added On Error Resume Next and discovered that at then end, of the run the last file is being duplicated but there is no full path on that same row, thus an extra row with only the last folder is populating an extra row.
https://i.imgur.com/hhCeCI0.png

Comment: The last thing you need is `On Error Resume Next`... you want to break when that error is thrown, and inspect the inputs and see why `UBound(a)-1` is out of range for `a` in that specicfic case.

Comment: Yes, using `On Error Resume Next` allowed me to see the end result of the error, I have inspected "files" and the last file in locals window is without value, thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

@MathieuGuindon resolved, thank you for your input which produced the successful result, just added checking if value is null, below:

```
`' extract last folder in path
Dim a As Variant
i = 5
For n = LBound(files) To UBound(files)
    a = Split(files(n), "\")
    If Not Fnameinloop = "" Then
    Fnameinloop = a(UBound(a) - 1)
    Cells(i, 1).Value = Fnameinloop
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Next n
`
```